# print the output on the same line as the input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a program to compute the greatest common divisor (GCD) of two given integers using the Euclidean Algorithm. The input contains two positive integers, x and y, separated by a white space. When 0 0 is entered the program terminates. I just got into Python and I'm definitely a noob at programming so my coding practices may be a bit rough. I am trying to have the computed GCD printed on the same line as the input. How do I print that computed value to the same line I entered the two integers on?

it would look something like this when done entering:

Input:

210 45        15

This is all I've been able to do:

Input:

210 45

15

I have this code so far for python 2.7:

```
def gcd (x, y):              # Greatest Common Divisor function
    if x > y:
        r = x%y                  # r = x divided by y and gives the remainder
        if r == 0:                  # if the division of x and y has no remainder, return y because y is the gcd.
            return y                #This is true because no number may have a divisor greater than the number itself (non-negative).  
        else:
            return gcd(y, r)            #if a = bt+r, for integers t and r, then gcd(x,y) = gcd(b,r)
    if x < y:
        x, y = y, x                 # value swapping
        return gcd(x, y)


getinput = True         
while(getinput):
                                     #list created for storing user entered values
    ssplit = []
    s = raw_input('Input: \n ')        # read a string of data, no evaluation by python
    ssplit = s.split(' ')           # read values between whitespace
    x = int(ssplit[0])          # place value from raw_input() into list
    y = int(ssplit[1])

    if( x != 0 and y != 0 ):        #tests to see if gcd needs to be evaluated
        print (gcd (x, y))
    else:
        getinput = False        # input was 0 0
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to ask a question :)

Comment: Not possible without some extreme output handling. Start with http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html

Comment: perhaps I'll have to redo this then. Additionally I need to take in multiple lines of integer pairs. I could keep adding variable pairs to a list manually and then when the input 0 0 is entered the program  stops taking in integer pairs and computes and prints the integers stored in the list and the gcd.

Comment: For the record, the reason this is hard is that when you entered the input, you terminated it with a newline. That newline moved your cursor down inside your *terminal*, which python knows nothing about. Can you just print the input followed by the output on the same line?

Comment: If you want something a little more fleshed out than ncurses, you could take a look at http://excess.org/urwid/, a great module which provides nice MVC ncurses-driven widgets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get away without curses, this may help. It cleans the screen after each enter but remembers the old output and redraws it.

```
import functools
import platform
import subprocess
import sys

def use_full_screen(question=None, history=None):
    if platform == 'win32':
        cls_cmd = 'cls'
    else:
        cls_cmd = 'clear'
    subprocess.call(cls_cmd)
    if history:
        print history
    if question is not None:
        return raw_input(question)


def make_screen(question, func, input_converter, max_repeat=9999):
    question += ': '
    def make_history(question, args, res):
        history = question[:-1]
        for arg in args:
            history += ' {}'.format(arg)
        history += ' {}'.format(res)
        return history

    def modfiy_input_converter(input_converter):

        @functools.wraps(input_converter)
        def converter(input_string):
            if input_string.strip() in ['exit', 'quit']:
                sys.exit(0)
            try:
                args = input_converter(input_string)
            except ValueError as err:
                msg = err.message
                msg += '\nInvalid input contine y/n: '
                cont = use_full_screen(msg,  history)
                if cont.strip() and cont in ['y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes']:
                    return converter(use_full_screen(question, history))
                sys.exit(0)
            return args
        return converter

    input_converter = modfiy_input_converter(input_converter)
    history = None
    args = input_converter(use_full_screen(question))
    res = func(*args)
    history = make_history(question, args, res)
    args = input_converter(use_full_screen(question, history))
    for _ in xrange(max_repeat):
        res = func(*args)
        history +='\n' + make_history(question, args, res)
        args = input_converter(use_full_screen(question, history))
    use_full_screen(history=history)
```

This is your function:

```
def gcd (x, y):
    """Greatest Common Divisor function"""
    if x > y:
         # r = x divided by y and gives the remainder
        r = x % y
        if r == 0:
            # if the division of x and y has no remainder, return y
            # because y is the gcd.
            # This is true because no number may have a divisor greater than
            # the number itself (non-negative).
            return y
        else:
             #if a = bt+r, for integers t and r, then gcd(x,y) = gcd(b,r)
            return gcd(y, r)
    elif x < y:
         # value swapping
        x, y = y, x
        return gcd(x, y)
    else:
        return x
```

You need to write function that converts the input:

```
def input_converter_gcd(input_string):
    try:
        values = tuple(int(x) for x in input_string.split())
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("Please enter integer numbers.")
    if len(values) != 2:
        raise ValueError(
            "Exactly 2 items needed but {:d} entered.".format(len(values)))
    return values
```

Raise a `ValueError` with a talking message. This message will be shown to the user.

Finally start the program:

```
question = 'Enter two numbers'
make_screen(question, gcd, input_converter_gcd, max_repeat=10)
```